# How to Set existing qml UI to widget container in QT?

Tags: qt

I had Widget as you see in this picture below and  I want to set my qml file to widget container which is shown in the above picture.

**how should I do this?**

[image: my mainwindow ui]

**here is my code :**

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QQuickView     *view;
    QWidget        *qmlWidgt;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    view     = new QQuickView(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/wave.qml")));
    qmlWidgt = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
    // setCentralWidget(qmlWidgt)
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: show your code as text, not images

Comment: you didn't clarify your question well, I didn't understand you want to use other UI from other classes in mainwindow UI ? at the end of the question you say want to set qml in the widget. it's different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your question I also create your UI like this:

[image]

then I create qml UI for example Red rectangle like this:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle
    {
        id:tmpRect
        anchors.fill: parent

        color: "red"
    }

}
```

**In mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QQuickView>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QQuickView     *view;
    QWidget        *qmlWidgt;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**In mainwindow.cpp** :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    view     = new QQuickView(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    qmlWidgt = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);
    ui->widget->layout()->addWidget(qmlWidgt);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**output** :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I'm a beginner at designing UI in Qt. but when implementing your code, it's an error that "The program has unexpectedly finished." and I don't why it is.

Comment: Your widget should have layout , set one grid layout for it,look at my ui picture. This because i add qmlwidget in widget layout

Comment: I Couldn't set the layout to my widget in UI. but I set that in CPP and by code manually and it worked

Comment: It's too easy , first put one button inside widget , then set grid layout for widget , then remove button . This easily makes you widget inside layout , in the end don't forget to push green ticks in this answer :-) @amirmat98